# Windows phone 8.1 app crash. How can I see the exception?

Tags: memory, crash, windows-phone-8.1

I have an application in Windows Phone 8.1. I debug it in an actual device and it works ok. However, when I run the app outside the visual studio, sometimes (random) it crashes.

Is there any way to see if there is an exception? In Android and iOS you can see the log although application is not running on Debug.

I think maybe it could be a memory problem, I load a lot of data. How can I check if this is the problem?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *automatic* logging for you, but you can use the global exception event:

```
Application.Current.UnhandledException += ...
```

There you can get your exception: Put it in a log file, just show a message dialog, etc.

Comment: Is it all exceptions handled with this event? If I have a OutOfMemoryException, this event will be fired? Many times, I don't receive anything. Thanks

Comment: Not Sure. Might be it does not get critical ex like outOfMemory or stackOverflow. (Can't find out right now.)

Comment: I can say for sure that some critical exceptions like AccessViolationException don't raise that event and crash the app directly.

Comment: Late to the show, but just wanted to add this limitation I came across this: 

    "A notable limitation is that the UnhandledException event arguments don’t contain as much detail as the original exception as propagated from app code" 

More: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, where I was getting not enough quota is available to process this command windows phone 8.1

Windows phone 8.1 have bug for navigate frame.

I replaced :

`Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondXAML));`

To :

`await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondXAML)));`

guys now no above exception. not enough quota is available to process this command windows phone 8.1

Tested 100 times calling. not crashing.